# Такой вопрос, есть ошибки в коде, помогите пожалуйста решить

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки, функции

**Вот ОШИБКИ:**

> Ошибка    C2660    strtok_s: функция не принимает 2 аргументов    Строка  51
>   Ошибка    C2660    strtok_s: функция не принимает 2 аргументов    Строка  58
>   Ошибка (активно)  E0165   слишком мало аргументов в вызове
>   функции   Строка  51   Ошибка (активно)   E0165   слишком мало аргументов в
>   вызове функции    Строка  58

*Буду рад помощи*

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <random>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #pragma warning (disable:4996);
    using namespace std;
    int CountWords(char* str1, char* str2)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char* pos = strchr(str1, str2[0]);
        do
        {
            if (!strncmp(&pos[0], str2, strlen(str2)))
                count++;
            pos = strchr(&str1[strlen(str1) - strlen(pos) + 1], str2[0]);
        } while (pos);
        return count;
    }
    int CountSentenses(char* str)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
            if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
                count++;
        return count;
    }
    int PointsCommas(char* str)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
            if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == ',')
                count++;
        return count;
    }
    char ReverseStr(char* str)
    {
        char tmp[10000];
        strcpy_s(tmp, str);
        for (int i = 0, j = strlen(tmp) - 1; i <= j + i; i++, j--)
            str[i] = tmp[j];
        return *str;
    }
    void ReverseSentences(char *str)
    {
        char *buf = strtok_s(str, ".!?");
        while (buf)
        {
            for (int i = strlen(str); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                cout << str[i];
            }
            buf = strtok_s(NULL, ".!?");
        }

}
```

Comment: и правильно ругается - strtok_s требует трех параметров, а Вы даете два. Может быть Вы просто взяли старый код с strtok и увидев ругань компилятора просто добавили _s

Comment: Передайте еще и адрес указателя, который будет указывать на другую часть строки: `char* p = nullptr;
    char* buf = strtok_s(str, ".!?", &p);`

Comment: Теперь вот что:
(Ошибка LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1 Строка 1 )
(Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) Строка 1)

Comment: Теперь уже ругается на то, что нет функции `main`. Она обязана присутствовать, если собирается исполняемый файл, а не библиотека.

Comment: Оно все равно не работает как надо по заданию может кто-то помочь пожалуйста Вот какие задачи:Есть некоторый текст. Используя стандартные строковые функции из библиотеки языка 
    • Посчитайте количество вхождений слово, заданного пользователем
    • Посчитайте количество предложений в тексте
    • Количество точек и запятых
    • Переверните весь текст целиком
    • Переверните каждое предложение в тексте